# Format razor view and add missing ID attributes

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013

Does Visual Studio 2013 have a shortcut or extension to clean up a document and add automatically generated ID attributes to controls where its missing? I'm also open to trying the find and replace regex where I need something along the lines of:

```
Find: All <input /> which dont have ID=""
Replace: <input ID="Textbox{n}" /> where n could be an incremental number
```

Not sure if any of these are possible.

Comment: You want to assign to all your input fields an auto-generated id with a random incremental number at the end? Can I ask you what for?

Comment: Well not really "at the end". It could be anywhere only if the ID attribute doesnt exist. The reason to do this beyond me as well. Our automation testers want all interactive elements to have locator ID's.

Comment: The logic you need is a bit advanced, so I would create a little command-line application that loops through all the *.cshtml files looking for <input /> tags. If a target is found, check if the string contains the ID. If not, add it with the incremental suffix.